# How to set a portion of the status line a certain color only if an element is evaluated- Vim

Tags: vim

In Vim I'm trying to make my status-line to work how I want it to.
Here's what I'm going for:
When the file I'm editing has been saved, I want it to look like this when saved: 
[image: Ideal-Saved]

And this when unsaved:
[image: Actual-Saved]

The former I see, but I get this when saved:
[image: Ideal-Unsaved]

(If those are too small to see, you can get the links [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJNNq.png), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAKDL.png), and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCzYm.png))

Here's what I have so far:

```
set statusline=%1*\ %n:\ %f\ %y\ %(%#mid#%m%)%=%1*%6v%6l\%6L\ %*
```

Any suggestions?

Ideally I would like to be able to see the top when unsaved and the second one when saved.

### Edit

After some searching I've come up with this, which seems like as good a start as any:

```
highlight User1 guibg=Black guifg=DarkYellow
highlight mid guibg=DarkRed guifg=Yellow
set statusline=%1*\ %n:\ %f\ %y\ %=%6v%6l\%6L\ %*
autocmd InsertChange * if (&modified) | set statusline=%1*\ %n:\ %f\ %y\ %#mid#%m%=%1*%6v%6l\%6L\ %* | endif
autocmd BufWrite * set statusline=%1*\ %n:\ %f\ %y\ %=%6v%6l\%6L\ %*
```

However, I can't seem to figure out when `InsertChanged` is actually called.

Comment: Docs at `:help autocmd` say `InsertChange  when typing <Insert> while in Insert or Replace mode` I just tested all your lines substituting `InsertCharPre` and it appears to do what you're asking.

Comment: Not exactly, though; notice how when you undo in normal mode it doesn't detect it

Comment: I was trying to workout something using a userdef function, but haven't been able to get it to go.

Comment: I tested out `InsertChange` like so `autocmd InsertChange * q` and it did not quit when I edited in insert mode. Maybe I'm failing to understand the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I found a solution that works for all my purposes:

```
set laststatus=2
highlight User1 guibg=Black guifg=DarkYellow
highlight mid guibg=DarkRed guifg=Yellow

let s:default = '%1* %n: %f %y %=%6v%6l%6L %*'
let s:changed =  '%1* %n: %f %y %#mid#%m%=%1*%6v%6l%6L %*'

fun IsModified()
    if &modified
        return s:changed
    endif
    return s:default
endfun
autocmd BufEnter * set statusline=%!IsModified()
autocmd BufLeave * let &l:statusline = IsModified()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you can use `:autocmd`s to update the statusline colors. However, `InsertChange` does not trigger when you think it is; it is merely for switching between normal inserting and overriding. Unfortunately, there's no exact event for "buffer changed"; you can trigger on `InsertEnter` and `CursorHold`, and then check the `&modified` flag.

My [StatusLineHighlight plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3383) indicates the state of the buffer (modified, readonly, unmodifiable, special non-file "scratch") / window (is preview window) by changing the highlighting of the window's status line. You can either use it directly, or at least find useful implementation hints for your own one.

Comment: I tested your plugin and it seems to me that it doesn't recognize undo's and redo's, etc.

Comment: Yes, not immediately, because there's a tradeoff between being triggered too often and too infrequent.